# AWS API Gateway: Best practice for API key

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

What are best practices for API Keys within AWS API Gateway?

- One APIKey per customer
  OR
- One APIKey per customer and API (so customers would have to use a different key for every API they use)

What are the Pros and Cons for each alternative?

Do we lose flexibility when customers have a single APIKey for every API?

Answer (score 1):

I am always advising to have a single apikey for each client. That means single key for each Api. This way you will be able to easier diagnose which application/service is sending requests. Additionally you put yourself in a position that key rotation will only impact a single client. Furthermore you can make a great use of usage plans to throttle your clients one by one so that it is not going to impact other clients using the same API gateway.

In terms of flexibility, you as an owner of API gateway, your job is to protect your api so that each client can use it in a reasonable way up to predefined limits. Therefore, single key for each client is absolutely the right way to go.

Comment: Do not forget that the default limit is 500 API keys per account and per region.  Having one API key per customer is not scalable.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html